# Query Dataset for count

Tags: c#, linq

How do i get the count of

```
var resHT = from row in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
            where row.Field<int>("a") == Convert.ToInt32(a.Value) && row.Field<int>("b") == 1
            select new {
                        TypeDescription = row.Field<string>("c"),
                        NameOrSpecs = row.Field<string>("d"),
                        AvailabilityBy = row.Field<DateTime?>("e")
                        };
```

How do I get count of resHT.I am little new to linq

Comment: var count = resHT.Count();

Comment: @reggaeguitar I had tried that but it gives me error of anonymous type. Any other suggestion

Comment: `var count =resHT.ToList().Count();`

Comment: @ps2goat thanks it worked. Why do i need ToList() if you dont mind explaining.

Comment: You could also do var count = resHT.ToArray().Length;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var count = resHT.ToList().Count();
```

By doing a `Select` with the `new` command, you are effectively creating an `IQueryable` of your anonymous type.  I don't know the exact reason why the code errors without the `ToList()`, but adding the `ToList()` turns your return data into a `List` of your anonymous type.  The `List` class has a count property on it, so that's why I had you do a `ToList`.

I do know that if you do LINQ-to-SQL, `ToList` forces the query to actually execute, which would then pull down all the data that matches and create your anonymous types, which could then be counted.  If you're working with an in-memory `DataTable`, I'm not sure of why it needs this to work.  I haven't done too much LINQ against DataTables, so I haven't played around with it very much.